# Moles fails when building .NET 4.0 system assemblies

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, moles

When running the command to build the .net 4.0 system assemblies for moles an error is encountered: MSIL error while compiling the generated code (-1007 - 0
xfffffc11) when generating for the system assembly. I've tried the fix to use the previous version with the /uninstall switch but dont think that works anymore. Does anyone know how to fix this issue for moles?